# Tricky join based on results of an aggregate evaluation

Tags: sql-server, join, filtering, aggregate

In SQL Server 2008, I have 3 tables: Definitions, Params, and Items. The fist table contains the min and max value that a Param may be. Params contains 0 or more parameters against a given definition, for an item. I wish to get the valid Item IDs by doing the appropriate conditional joins/evals.

To illustrate:

[image]

ItemID = 1 would be returned because nothing in Params violates Definitions.Min|Max.

ItemsID = 2 would not be returned because Hi = 103 violates Definitions.Max where DefID = 2. Given this, the fact the last entry violates Definitions.Low is inconsequential, but shown for clear illustration.

ItemID = 3 will match because it has a Param that is within range. There is no need to join all Definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT  *
FORM    Items i INNER JOIN
        Params p    ON  i.ItemID = p.ItemID INNER JOIN
        Definitions d   ON  p.DefinationID = d.DEfinationID
WHERE   p.Hi <= d.Max
AND         p.Low >= d.Min
```

**EDIT**

Have a look at this full example

```
DECLARE @Items TABLE(
        ItemID INT
)
DECLARE @Params TABLE(
        DefID INT,
        ItemID INT,
        Low FLOAT,
        Hi FLOAT
)
DECLARE @Defs TABLE(
        DefID INT,
        [Min] FLOAT,
        [Max] FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO @Items SELECT 1
INSERT INTO @Items SELECT 2
INSERT INTO @Items SELECT 3

INSERT INTO @Params SELECT 1, 1, 11, 18
INSERT INTO @Params SELECT 1, 1, 13, 17
INSERT INTO @Params SELECT 2, 1, 25, 80

INSERT INTO @Params SELECT 1, 2, 12, 15
INSERT INTO @Params SELECT 1, 2, 14, 15
INSERT INTO @Params SELECT 2, 2, 50, 80
INSERT INTO @Params SELECT 2, 2, 50, 103
INSERT INTO @Params SELECT 2, 2, 10, 80

INSERT INTO @Params SELECT 2, 3, 24, 60

INSERT INTO @Defs SELECT 1, 10, 20
INSERT INTO @Defs SELECT 2, 20, 100

;WITH InvalidValues AS (
        SELECT  DISTINCT
                i.ItemID
        FROM    @Items i INNER JOIN
                @Params p   ON  i.ItemID = p.ItemID INNER JOIN
                @Defs d ON  p.DefID = d.DefID
        WHERE   p.Low < d.[Min]
        OR      p.Hi > d.[Max]
)
SELECT  *
FROM    @Items i 
WHERE   NOT EXISTS  (
                        SELECT  1
                        FROM    InvalidValues
                        WHERE   ItemID = i.ItemID
                    )
AND     EXISTS  (
                    SELECT  1
                    FROM    @Params p
                    WHERE   ItemID = i.ItemID
                )
```

**REsult**

```
ItemID
1
3
```

Comment: @astander thanks - but I wish it were that simple. Running this gives me 4 * ID = 1 (in my data test case). If I throw 1 param out of bounds, then I simply get 3 * ID = 1. Of course I need 0 * ID = 1.

Comment: OK, so if at any stage a para is out of bounds, you wish that item excluded?

Comment: 100%. You have inspired what could be an answer: to count the "in bounds", use cross-apply to count the "all", and only grab the records where the two #s are =. However, for speed sake, I want it to NOT join needlessly (we're talking millions of records).

Comment: Ps. I threw in an EXCEPT rather that a CTE :)

Comment: I just realized that I can't quite just say "SELECT * FROM Items"... it must only return the joined values.

Comment: I had a feeling I wasn't missing the solution for no reason. I ran a test where I did a join for the positive and then a join for the negative (EXCEPT). Performance was dismal. I am looking for an "in 1 step" solution.

Comment: In your example, if we add "INSERT INTO @Items SELECT 4", this should NOT come back in the results. It has no joins.

Comment: OK, see EDIT then. Added an EXISTS check for in Params

Comment: In the end, I couldn't quite use this solution because I was also binding an additional data source. I didn't mention this in the question because I didn't think it would influence the problem. I managed to solve it elegantly with a CROSS APPLY :)